# Repeating adjectives and adverbs after conjuctions

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, conjunctions, recurring-events

Do adjectives or adverbs associate with the second noun or adjective after the first one or do they need to be repeated?

> This dichotomy can at times be too inclusive or **(too)** exclusive?

Does the adverb need to be repeated, or does it also refer to the second adjective after the conjunction?

Comment: I'd say it's usual to include it. There _is_ an ambiguity if you leave it out (though the default reading would be unchanged).

Comment: At least from a speaking perspective, I feel like it may depend on what you're saying and how you're saying it.

Comment: Modifiers ordinarily distribute over a conjunction, just as multipliers distribute over addition: aX(b+c) = aXb + aXc. But you don't have to distribute them.  If two expressions are equal, you can substitute either one for the other, as clarity and euphony may dictate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen it both ways. I believe it depends on clarity. For example:

`"The deep south is too hot, humid, and wet for my liking."` Its clear that the adverb applies to the list of adjectives.

Here is a similar question with an answer you might find useful. [Repeat Adverb in a List.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/302464/repeat-adverb-in-a-list-or-is-one-time-enough)